# Перегрузка оператора +

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Пишу свой класс одномерного массива, для которого перегружаю операции, в том числе и сложения +.

```
class Array
{
public:
    Array();
    Array(const int SIZE);
    Array(const Array& array);
    ~Array();

    void getArrayToConsole();
    void sortingMinMax();
    void searchValue();
    void setSIZE();
    void setValues();
    int getSIZE();

    int operator [](const int index);
    const Array &operator =(const Array& array);
    Array operator +(Array& array);

    static int numberOfObjectGlobal;
    
private:
    int numberOfObject;
    int* pointer;
    int SIZE = 10;
};

int Array::numberOfObjectGlobal = 0;

Array::Array()
{
    numberOfObject = numberOfObjectGlobal++;
    pointer = new int[SIZE];

    for (int  i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        pointer[i] = numberOfObject;
}

Array::Array(const int SIZE)
{
    numberOfObject = numberOfObjectGlobal++;
    this->SIZE = SIZE;
    pointer = new int[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        pointer[i] = numberOfObject;
}

Array::Array(const Array& array)
{
    delete [] pointer;
    numberOfObject = numberOfObjectGlobal++;
    SIZE = array.SIZE;
    pointer = new int[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        this->pointer[i] = array.pointer[i];
}

Array::~Array()
{
    delete [] pointer;
}

void Array::getArrayToConsole()
{
    std::cout << "Array "<<this->numberOfObject<<":\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        std::cout<<pointer[i]<<"\t";

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

const Array &Array::operator=(const Array& array)   
{
    if (&array != this)
    {
        delete[] pointer;
        SIZE = array.SIZE;
        pointer = new int[SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            pointer[i] = array.pointer[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

Array Array::operator+(Array &array)
{
    if (SIZE == array.SIZE)
    {
        std::cout << "==\n";
        Array result(SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            result.pointer[i] = pointer[i] + array.pointer[i];          
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "\n Error of objects SIZE compression: " << SIZE<<" and "<<array.SIZE << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    Array arr1;
    Array arr2;
    Array arr3;
    arr1.getArrayToConsole();
    arr2.getArrayToConsole();
    arr3.getArrayToConsole();


    arr1 = arr3 + arr2;
    
    arr1.getArrayToConsole();
    arr2.getArrayToConsole();
    arr3.getArrayToConsole();

    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: если даже взять самый простой случай, когда поля SIZE объектов равны, когда дело доходит до строчки `return result;` программа рушится возвращая непонятное многозначное отрицательное число. Я не могу понять где я ошибся.
P.S. Подобную задачку я нашел на одном не самом убогом сайте, посмотрел в ответах и там такой же код.

Comment: явно не хватает реализации конструкторов. Подозреваю, что там может быть припрятано парочка багов.

Comment: добавил в конце

Comment: Если вам надо просто поэлементно сложить элементы двух массивов одинакового размера, то это делается одним циклом, а у вас какая-то огромная функция

Comment: `pointer` в конструкторе копирования не инициализируется, так что `delete pointer;` — это UB, которое скорей всего и вызывает сегфолт... ну и `operator=` нужно посмотреть...

Comment: а я хочу сложение массивов разных размеров, но это не суть в моем вопросе

Comment: исправил в конструкторе копирования delete pointer на delete [] pointer, проблема осталась...или вы не про это? добавил оператор =

Comment: Сделайте [mre], заодно и ошибку локализуете

Comment: Делал, результат такой же

Comment: Так приведите его в вопросе, чтобы можно было запустить у себя

Comment: я вас понял, исправил

Comment: Пока что всё равно не воспроизводится https://godbolt.org/z/6eWzx4

Comment: добавил функцию вывода в консоль

Comment: Отрицательных чисел нет https://godbolt.org/z/vxnKEx

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что все скомпилировалось нормально?

Comment: @ВадимА, я про то что `delete` там вообще не должно быть...

Comment: @ВадимА ну справа же есть вывод программы, отрицательных чисел там нет

Comment: Fat-Zer спасибо! всё правильно, краш был из-за удаления еще не инициализированного указателя! убрал delete  - всё скомпилировалось

Comment: только не понятно каким образом конструктор копирования тут

Comment: @ВадимА, если кратко, то при `return result` создаётся временный объект, в который и копируется всё с помощью конструктора копирования. В любом букваре про это должен быть абзац-другой. Но так происходит не всегда см. RVO/NRVO/copy-elision. ЗЫ: при упоминании используй собаку `@`, дабы упоминания приходили.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```cpp
Array Array::operator+(Array &array)
{
    if (SIZE == array.SIZE)
    {
        std::cout << "==\n";
        Array result(SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            result.pointer[i] = *(pointer + i) + *(array.pointer + i);          
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: я бы сделал бинарный оператор через friend а не методом, и если операций + будет много лучше передавать по const& так как lvalue  ссылка не возьмет rvalue возвращаемый через return